# Trying to return single button based on text/innerText content using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, puppeteer

Using the following code snippet created by React, button names populated from server input.

```
<div class="layer-groups">
    <a class="btn group-btn active">Partners</a>
    <a class="btn group-btn">Live Layers</a>
    <a class="btn group-btn">My Layers</a>
    <a class="btn group-btn">Files & Data</a>
</div>
```

I need to first detect if the button exists then click it, validate it's state, etc.

These work, but always just gives me the first item in the array (as expected)

```
const [LiveLayersButton] = await page.$x("//a[@class='btn group-btn']");
const [PartnersButton] = await page.$x("//a[contains(@class,'btn group-btn')]");
```

These all return undefined (Even though they all return the right selector from the browser console)

```
const [LiveLayersButton] = await page.$x("//a[@class='btn group-btn'][contains(., 'Live Layers')]");
const [MyLayersButton] = await page.$x("//a[@class='btn group-btn'][contains(text(), 'My Layers')]");
const [PartnersButton] = await page.$x("//a[@class='btn group-btn'][contains(string(), 'Partners')]");
```

I could loop through the array and do page.evaluate() to click on the buttons, but that only solves the click, not the detect, validate state, etc where I need the ElementHandle

Comment: One added note. This is a popup window in a single-page-app. But this hasn't been an issue with puppeteer and jest until now. Going to console and typing: $x("//a[@class='btn group-btn'][contains(., 'Live Layers')]") works fine

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, tested with your source `HTML`:

```
const [partnersButton] = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'Partners')]");
const [liveLayersButton] = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'Live Layers')]");
const [myLayersButton] = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'My Layers')]");
const [filesAndDataButton] = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'Files & Data')]");

// Click on the button if it's existing.
if (partnersButton) await partnersButton.click();
```

Comment: Looks like that works for 3 out of the four for me. The Live Layers text is on another btn and it's getting clicked.  I was able to use your simplification and create this working answer: [LiveLayersButton] = await page.$x("//a[contains(@class, 'group-btn') and contains(., 'Live Layers')]");

Comment: Seems the syntax between chrome dev console and puppeteer are a little different, with latter being a little more strict. Taking out the double braces and adding an "and" did the trick. Thanks - Jeuke